# odd issues with Link regardless of fieldtype

Tags: content-query-web-part, hyperlink

I have a picture library and I am using unc path to very large files (Like engineering autocad files) that I can't store in SP.

I added a content Query WP and configured it so pictures are displayed with link to file. However, either SP or browser (ie, chrome, ff) is not rendering the url and gives me Invalid URL.

However, I can throw a cewp and html code file share href and it works.

Does it matter what type of page it is where I am throwing the cq web part? both title and pictureLink behaves the same way when they are populated with fileshare link (unc path).

From the pic library, view an item and click on either title (which is populated with file:\server\a\b\c\xyz.xlsx) or the pictureLink resolves the unc path.

So I am thinking either the page type or web part is the issue. Please suggest.

What are my options? kinda on a deadline.

Comment: How do you specify the UNC? It should be `file://server/share/dir/file`

Comment: What is the invalid url that the CQWP is giving you?

Comment: Are you sure the file extension is allowed on your farm? (check here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262496.aspx)